# MS Access max date and recent date and their respective qty

Tags: ms-access

Looking for MaxDate, its most recent date and the interval between.  Of the MaxDate and most recent, I also need the quantities for each so I can also find the interval

> Table "tblITEM_InventoryCount" structure is as follows:
>
> Item_No     Count Date      Qty
>
> 001         08/29/2015       12
>
> 001         08/15/2015       17
>
> 001         07/15/2015       19
>
> Item No 001
>
> Max(CountDate) 08/29/2015
>
> PriorCountDate 08/15/2015
>
> Interval Days (MaxDate-RecentDate) 14
>
> MaxDate Quantity 12
>
> PriorCountDate Quantity 17
>
> Interval Qty (17-12) 5

Currently using a query to find last two count dates for each ITEM_NO

```
SELECT tblITEM_InventoryCount.ITEM_NO, tblITEM_InventoryCount.Quantity, tblITEM_InventoryCount.CountDate
FROM tblITEM_InventoryCount
WHERE (((tblITEM_InventoryCount.CountDate)>=NthInGroup([tblITEM_InventoryCount].[ITEM_NO],2)))
ORDER BY tblITEM_InventoryCount.ITEM_NO, tblITEM_InventoryCount.CountDate DESC;
```

Then I am using a second query to calculate my data:

```
SELECT qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.ITEM_NO,      qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.CountDate, (SELECT MAX([CountDate]) FROM [qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS] AS [Old Orders] WHERE [Old Orders].[CountDate] < [qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS].[CountDate] AND [Old Orders].[ITEM_NO] = [qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS].[ITEM_NO]) AS PriorCountDate, [CountDate]-[PriorCountDate] AS DaysInterval, qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.Quantity, (SELECT Last([Quantity]) FROM [qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS] AS [OldCount] WHERE [OldCount].[Quantity] < [qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS].[Quantity] AND [OldCount].[ITEM_NO] = [qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS].[ITEM_NO]) AS PriorQuantity, [Quantity]-[PriorQuantity] AS QuantityInterval, [QuantityInterval]*30/[DaysInterval] AS [Usage]
FROM qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.ITEM_NO, qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.CountDate, qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.Quantity
ORDER BY qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.ITEM_NO, qryLAST2_InventoryCount_TRANSACTIONS.CountDate DESC;
```

I am not getting the results I need.  The query returns two record lines for each item along with their max or last countdate, the previous countdate, intervaldays, qty, last qty, and interval.

I need max or last countdate and its qty count and prior countdate and its qty count.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 select 
   tab.item_no, 
   tab.Max_Date, 
   tab.PriorCountDate, 
   DateDiff ("d", tab.Max_Date, tab.PriorCountDate) as IntervalDays,
   tab.MaxDateQty,
   tab.PriorCountDateQty,
   ( tab.MaxDateQty-tab.PriorCountDateQty) as IntervalQty,


 from

   ( select 
          temp1.item_no as item_no, 
          temp1.m as Max_Date, 
          (select MAX(count_date) from tblITEM_InventoryCount where count_date <> temp1.m ) as PriorCountDate,
          temp1.q as MaxDateQty,
          (select MAX(Qty) from tblITEM_InventoryCount where Qty <> temp1.q) as PriorCountDateQty,


     from

       ( select item_no as i, Qty as q, MAX(count_date) as m
         group by item_no, Qty ) as temp1

       inner join

          tblITEM_InventoryCount as temp2   

       on

          temp1.item_no = temp2.item_no 
    )
     as tab  ;
```

Comment: Thank you @Sagar but I am still having difficulty after pasting this code into the SQL View on a query.

Comment: @kduncan, Can you please mention what error is coming?